# Convergance of an alternating series

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
$a_n >0 , \lim _{n \to \infty} a_n =0$
Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges

**What I did**
I thought about the proof to Leibniz's theorem, but this question doesn't include $a_n$ being monotonous, So using the Cauchy criteria here is somewhat problematic for me.

Or maybe: from some point very close to 0 the sequence IS monotonous, so I can assume it's true from some place?

Or third thought:
I know that every sequence has a monotonic sub-sequence- I can prove that the alternating sum of that sub-sequence converges using Leibniz, but then what do I do with the rest of the numbers not in that sub-sequence?

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. Let $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for odd $n$, and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for even $n$. The series $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ does not converge. The sum of the negative terms is bounded below by $-\frac{2}{3}$, while the sum of the positive terms can be made arbitrarily large.